# Cannot invoke '+' with an argument list of type '(frame: CGRect)'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cgrect, cgfloat

I am trying to create a UIView from a CGRect frame. Every parameter in CGRectMake() are CGFloats.

```
var views:UIView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(CGFloat(hotspotScroll.frame.size.width * i + 20), CGFloat(10),CGFloat(hotspotScroll.frame.size.width - 40), CGFloat(hotspotScroll.frame.size.height - 20)))
```

But it gives me an error:

```
Cannot invoke '+' with an argument list of type '(frame: CGRect)'
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` needs to be a `CGFloat` for the `*` and `+` to work out right:

```
var views:UIView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(CGFloat(hotspotScroll.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i) + 20), CGFloat(10),CGFloat(hotspotScroll.frame.size.width - 40), CGFloat(hotspotScroll.frame.size.height - 20)))
```